# change PATH for building docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This command `sudo docker build -t mydocker .` build the image in `/var/lib/docker`. Is there a way to change it to another folder e.g. `/home/user1/docker`?

Comment: No, the build process is managed by the `docker` daemon, and will always take place wherever the docker storage dirver has allocated storage.

Comment: Is there a way to change where the docker deamon stores the data?

Comment: You can always create a symbolic link: `ln -s /where/you/want/it /var/lib/docker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restart the docker daemon with the `-g` option.

```
docker -d -g /home/user1/docker
```

or

```
docker -d --graph="/home/user1/docker"
```

Keep in mind that once you do this, all your images for that docker daemon instance will get stored on `/home/user1/docker`

And also that generally the Docker daemon runs a `root`. So it's probably better to specify a directory owned by `root`

Comment: Note that you probably don't *want* to put your docker storage in `/home`, because everything is going to be owned by `root`, which will just complicate your life at some point.  Better to mount additional storage on `/var/lib/docker` or point `docker` at a location outside of `/home`.

Comment: @larsks that's right... added more details to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the new version of Docker, you have to change daemon.json.

```
 sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

then add the path to the deamon JSON (In my case path is '/media/newhd/containers/')

```
{"data-root":"/media/newhd/containers/"}
```

After this restart the docker...

Comment: I installed Docker 20.10.1, build 831ebea, on Ubuntu, and the file /etc/docker/daemon.json doesn't exist.

Comment: @MazeGen if file not there you can create a file.

##Create or modify /etc/docker/daemon.json on the client machine